# How to align elements inside a row differently

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container inside which the child elements have col-md-2 and col-lg-3 classes applied and the data gets added dynamically.What i want to do is on the large screen if there are 3 columns present then the middle most should be centered and the last one on that particular row should be align to the end.If screen size is medium then there can be only 2 columns possible therefore the second element of every row should be remained aligned to the middle. But on small screen all should remain aligned to the center.

Here is what i have tried out https://jsfiddle.net/aeshna/w6e54jxg/15/

```css
.list-container {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.el-row-container {
  width: 95%;
}
.el-row-container .el-container {
  width: 410px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.data {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 291px;
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
   @media (min-width: $breakpoint-lg) {
  .align-middle {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .align-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 list-container">
    <div class="row el-row-container">
      <div class="el-container  col-md-2 col-lg-3"  ng-repeat="data in els"  ng-class="{'align-middle': $index%3 ===1, 'align-end': $index%3 === 2}">
        <div class="data">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Based on the index i'm assigning them align-middle and align-end class but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, you'd better use `align-self` css property instead of `justify-content`

Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/bmu0rdoc/3/

But your bootstrap usage seems a bit weird to me : when you add a `.col-{breakpoint}-{size}` class, bootstrap is trying to fill the parent with {size} rows. When you add a fixed width, you're breaking this column system : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid